# Fitting to histogram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have used below code to fit to my data's histogram:

```
histfit(data,40,'exponential')
```

The questions I can not answer are:

1- How can I find fit parameters of exponential fit?

2- How can I fit a power law to the histogram of data?

Any answer to these questions is highly appreciated.

I have a dataset and I want to fit a power law distribution to histogram of data.

Comment: It is not a hard question. I wonder why there is no one who could give an answer!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I think it is not clear what you want.

Comment: I have a dataset and I want to fit a power law distribution to histogram of data. @Royi

Answer (score 0):

The function which does the heavy lifting inside `histfit()` is [`fitdist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html).
This is the function which calculates the Distribution Parameters.

So you should do the following:

`pd = fitdist(data, 'exponential');`

To get the parameters of the Exponential Distribution.

Those are the distribution supported in `fitdist()`:

[image: MATLAB's fitdist() supported distributions]

Comment: Should I use pd = fitdist(hist(vec,30), 'exponential'); to find paameters of fitting to histogram?

Comment: No, `pd = fitdist(vec, 'exponential')`. I linked to the documentation. Look there.

Comment: What about power fitting?(second question)

Comment: I didn't understand what's power fitting. If you explain what you meant, I will answer.

Comment: The output is:  Exponential distribution
    mu = 86.5207   [86.3692, 86.6726]. What is mu?

Comment: Have you looked on the documentation I linked to: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html ? It links to the exponential distribution https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.exponentialdistribution-class.html. As you can see $ \mu $ is the mean of the distribution.

Comment: if you run cftool and putting your data there, there is lots of functions to fit: exponential, polynomial, power ... I mean these power distribution. It is not present in the image u inserted.  example of power function: f(x)=a*x^(b*x)

Comment: But I don't need the mean. I need a and b in p(x)= a* e^(b*x)

Comment: You asked for the exponential distribution which is defined by 1 parameter - its mean - https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exponential-distribution.html.

Comment: I'm familiar with that distribution. Look at the list above. Use what fit you best.

Comment: But there is no power low fit in above list

Comment: According to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Power-law_probability_distributions it seems the one of the logistics will assist you.